# use Flutter bloc to fetch data from Api in Listview element

Tags: api, flutter, bloc

I am trying to fetch data from two different APIs where the second depends on the first API as follows:
the first API: it is used to get the city id by its name, so I have to write the city name and the API will return the city id.
the second API: is used to get the city image by its id, so I have to enter the city id to get the city image.
I used Flutter bloc in my app to manage interfaces and their states, as follows:

```
BlocBuilder<FirstApiBloc, CityState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is CitiesIdsLoaded) {
        List<CityDetail> citiesList = state.citiesDetails;

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: citiesList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             BlocProvider.of<CityPhotoBloc>(context).add(LoadCityPhoto( 
            cityId: hotelsList[index].id.toString()));

            return Card(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child:
        BlocBuilder<CityPhotoBloc, CityPhotoState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                        if (state is PhotoCityLoaded) {
                          return Image.network(state.photosUrl);
                        } else 
                        return Container();
                      },
                    ),
```

as you can see in the snippet above, I used

```
 BlocProvider.of<CityPhotoBloc>(context).add(LoadCityPhoto( 
            cityId: hotelsList[index].id.toString()));
```

to fetch the photo for every city in the listview, But the problem is that all the images shown in the list are the same image because all the elements of the list depend on one state and that changes in each element in the list when BlocProvider is called as shown in the snippet, what should i do to get the image for each element in the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `photosUrl` a `String` that holds the url of a single city in your state (in `CityPhotoBloc`), do as you did in `FirstApiBloc` where you defined a list of city id's to be held in your state, so do it here and also define list of urls called photosUrls,then in your ListView instead of using `state.photosUrl` you will use `state.photosUrl[index]` to get the url.

Also try using a `BlocConsumer` instead of `BlocBuilder` and see if you can implement `buildWhen` method to only build widgets in list view if necessary

```
Edit:(more clarification):
```

From flutter.dev:

> In contrast to the default ListView constructor, which requires
>   creating all items at once, the ListView.builder() constructor creates
>   items as they’re scrolled onto the screen.

This means that if you write this to get url of a city photo:

> BlocProvider.of(context).add(LoadCityPhoto( 
>               cityId: hotelsList[index].id.toString()));

and you have million cities, then not million events will be dispatched at same time, that would have happened with normal `ListView` ,while with `ListView.builder`, as the quoted text says, will only create children on demand and since the event is fired in the same bloc of code where a child is created then also the event will be fired on demand

I hope it is clear now

read more about ListView.builder [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Comment: lets make the code more clear, I need the city name, City space and City population from the first API, so when the user goes to cities interface it will display a list with all cities and their name ...etc, if I try to load all cities images from the second API it will take a very long time to load them, so I have an idea to load just the cities that appear in the listview

Comment: my answer didn't say load all city images, it said load all cities urls, and ListView.builder will handle loading images of only cities in scope, please read the answer again you may have misunderstood it

Comment: there are thousands of cities around the world, I don't want to retrieve all their images at once, Because the user will not likely see all the cities, but I want to retrieve the images of the city that currently appear in the listview only. As for the cities that do not appear, there is no need to retrieve their pictures, but this will be done when they appear. so your solution will take a very long time to retrieve all images' URLs from the API and the user will likely see only a few of them

Comment: @omarshady see the more clariffied answer please

Comment: I know that, and as you noticed I have already used listview. builder, the problem in my code is that all listview items take the same image, I guess that because all listview items take the same state then when the state ( which represent the image ur) changed in any item it will change in all items. is there any way to keep the state, so after a specific item takes the state it wouldn't change even if a new state is transmitted by bloc? is it right to use bloc in my example or not? I mean when I use blocBuilder inside listview how will its behavior be? will all items take the same state?